# output specific list items in json

Tags: python, json

I have some list items I'd like to print as json, instead of just the values.

my list items:

```
ans = "{ct} {p}  {v} {f}".format(ct=item['COUNTRY'], p=totalPrice,v= item['VARIABLE_COST'],f=item['FIXED_OVERHEAD'])
```

This prints out for example:

```
MX 336100.00  100.0 32.0
BR 210201.00  201.0 20.0
```

I want to print out each key/value pair like:

```
[{
"COUNTRY":"MX",
"COMMODITY":"mango",
"FIXED_OVERHEAD":"32.00",
"VARIABLE_COST":"1.24"
}]
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can create a list of dictionaries, like you explained, and use pprint for pretty printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use json.dumps() to serialize your list value in a json string format also the dumps method takes in a second parameter called indent, to make the output look nice for example indent=4. Hope it helps.